# Unsubscribe URLs in emails being altered by firewalls

Tags: email, unsubscribe

We are experiencing a significant number of links in our emails being altered by email firewalls resulting in recipients experiencing peculiar unsubscribe form behavior that is troublesome.  For example, one firewall product replaces any email address in our unsubscribe URLs with mail=nobody@mycraftmail.com.

Has anyone explored an alternative method for unsubscribe links that works well?  We are considering using cid and checksum, but the form won't work once the token expires.  We are using CiviCRM 5.21.3 on Drupal 7.73.  Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: If it helps you can increase the checksum expiry time at Admin - System Settings - Misc. It's the first option "Checksum Lifespan".

Comment: Thanks-- we had increased it by a week, but would like to avoid extending it beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [Advanced Newsletter Management Extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/newsletter/en/latest/). It allows you to configure mailing subscription preference pages in CiviCRM. The extension will then make this information available via its REST API and an external system can generate the pages and present them to your contacts.

As it does require some work to set up mailing preference forms separately from CiviCRM, it's not a quick and easy fix.

Comment: Thanks-- I had not seen that extension-- it is not listed in the Extensions Directory.  I will check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately not all extensions are listed there and getting an extension listed for "automated distribution" can be a bit cumbersome. Hence it's wise always to google for extensions in addition to checking the extension directory.